# fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String

Tags: swift, string, char, fatal-error

So I have function that strips off a trailing ", " (comma + space) at the end of a string and I'm getting the above error even though I'm ensuring that the string is not empty. The following code:

```
print("stripping trailing commas")
        for var detail in details {
            if detail.contains(",") {
print(detail)
                detail.remove(at: detail.endIndex)    // <-- Removes last space
                detail.remove(at: detail.endIndex)    // <-- Removes last comma
            }
        }
```

...results int the following console output:

```
stripping trailing commas
2016, 
fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String
```

The first instance `detail.remove(at: detail.endIndex)` is being highlighted by the debugger, and while I can't be sure the space is present from the console message, I'm adding ", " at the end of each entry in a list so any string that actually contains a comma should not only have characters (as the console indicates) but it should have an extra two chars at the end that need to be stripped.

Thanks in advance, for any help on **what's causing the error** and how to resolve?

Comment: In both cases, the index needs to be 1 character ahead.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `at: detail.index(before: detail.endIndex)` did the trick. Want to throw it up as a quick answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this without using `import Foundation` (needed for `contains()`) or calculating indexes would be something like this:

```
let details = ["one, two, three, ", "a, b", "once, twice, thrice, so nice, ", ""]

let filtered = details.map { (original: String) -> String in
  guard original.hasSuffix(", ") else { return original }
  return String(original.characters.dropLast(2))
}

print(filtered) // -> "["one, two, three", "a, b", "once, twice, thrice, so nice", ""]\n"
```

This won't remove any empty strings that are in the returned array. If you need that functionality it can easily be added.

Comment: Interesting, although if I was trying to do that `details.map { $0.characters.split(separator: ",").first }` might be more succinct. However, in this instance each detail is a full list (i.e. ["one, two, three, ", "a, b, c, ", etc...]) and I only want to remove the last (extraneous) comma.

Comment: That code won’t work. It produces results with the type `Array<Optional<Swift.String.CharacterView>>`. That’s why my example is more complicated, to get it to `Array<String>`. But yep, if there is more than one comma my code wouldn’t work. I’m updating it to match your requirement.

Comment: Your update has been very helpful, thanks a lot. I can't see it anymore, but I thought your original version returned optionals (there was a return nil in the guard statement), and I'm not importing Foundation but can still call contains... A more comprehensive and informative response though so thanks again for taking the time and I'll change the answer to yours.

Comment: If you click on the “edited __ ago” link under the answer you can see the past revisions. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40371076/revisions) are the revisions for this answer. 

I did return `nil`, as part of an `Optional`, in order to filter out empty strings and errors. If you have a container of `Optional` then `flatMap` will unwrap the `Optional` and drop any that are `nil`. 

I could do that here too but I simplified it a bit and left empty strings alone.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was wondering why you went for flatMap instead of map.

Answer (score 10):

Try change

```
detail.remove(at: detail.endIndex)
```

to

```
detail.remove(at: detail.index(before: detail.endIndex))
```